# Unnumbered section header (\section command with star) with optional argument

Tags: sectioning, unnumbered-sections

I wish to have an ***unnumbered*** **section header with an optional argument.** *(Should I refer to it as a section header, a section heading, or a section title?)*

Here's an example with a *numbered* section header with the `article` document class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section[Reference Sheet for Python]{Reference Sheet for
Python\\ (adapted from learnxinyminutes.com)}

\end{document}
```

[image: numbered section]

The optional argument `[Reference Sheet for Python]` is the short section header.

Now I wish to make the section *unnumbered*. This attempt (using `\section*[Short header]{Long header}`) fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*[Reference Sheet for Python]{Reference Sheet for
Python\\ (adapted from learnxinyminutes.com)}

\end{document}
```

and gives this result:

[image: unnumbered section, first attempt]

Similarly, this attempt (using `\section[Short header]*{Long header}`) fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section[Reference Sheet for Python]*{Reference Sheet for
Python\\ (adapted from learnxinyminutes.com)}

\end{document}
```

and gives this result:

[image: unnumbered section, second attempt]

In order to make the section *unnumbered*, do I need to somehow redefine `\section`? [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528355/15622) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528333/15622) presents a way to redefine `\chapter` in the `book` document class. Do I need to analogously redefine `\section` in order to accommodate `\section*[Short header]{Long header}` in the `article` document class?

Comment: The usual reason for the `*` is to not have the section header appear in the toc.  The usual reason for the `[]` is to have a different section title appear in the toc.  Those two reasons go against each other.  Do you have a different reason for what you're going?

Comment: On naming I prefer: `section heading` that refers to the heading assembly,i.e,  section number, and section title. Chpter heading You also have  running head, what goes on every page. To me it appearshas also a label `chapter`. Are you trying to have a section title and and section subtitle? For this you will need a special command.

Comment: You can set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`, then the section is not longer numbered.

Comment: What is the main reason for this? Is it because of the header on the page (because `\section*` isn't added to the ToC, nor do you seem to use/need a ToC)?

Comment: It'd be better to edit more information concerning your use case and desired output, as there are many possible answers to the question as asked, but may not meet your final needs. For example: (A) Are you only going to be using unnumbered sections? If so you can suppress all numbering in a variety of ways. (B) Are you really trying to add additional "subtitle" info to one (or several) sections? (C) What is the purpose of using `\section*`? `\section*` does more than just omit section numbers; are all its actions desirable? (D) Why specify a short title? Where do you expect it to be used?

Answer (score 0):

The optional argument of `\section` is used for the page style make (usually used in the page header with page style `headings`) and for the entry to the table of contents. `\section*` does neither set the page mark nor add an entry to the table of contents. So having an optional argument wouldn't make sense.

If you want a `\section` without number but with entry to the table of contents and setting the page mark, you can  set counter `secnumdepth` to a value less than 1:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[Reference Sheet for Python]{Reference Sheet for
Python\\ (adapted from learnxinyminutes.com)}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

But as you can see in the header of the second page, this would add a wrong section number to the page header.

Alternatively you can indeed use `\section*`, but make the entries manually:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Reference Sheet for
  Python\\ (adapted from learnxinyminutes.com)%
  \markright{\MakeUppercase{Reference Sheet for Python}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Reference Sheet for Python}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional note: There are classes like the KOMA-Script classes, that provide extra features for not numbered headings with entry to the ToC and the page header. For example:

```latex
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses,automark]{scrartcl}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addsec[Reference Sheet for Python]{Reference Sheet for
  Python\\ (adapted from learnxinyminutes.com)}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]